# Facebook share with Image / Link, Title, Description

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I need to share a photo/link in Facebook, with custom title, custom description and photo thumbnail.

share link is,

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D=From+the+album%3A+Timeline+Photos&p%5Bsummary%5D=my+5th+%231+album+and+now+i%27m+hosting+SNL.+u+made+this+happen.+thank+u+to+all+my+beliebers.+%0D%0A%0D%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsmarturl.it%2FJBBelieveAcoustic&p%5Burl%5D=By+Justin+Bieber&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=https%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhphotos-ak-ash4%2Fs480x480%2F485171_10151590726513888_1592108632_n.jpg&

I'm getting "Could not post to Wall". The message could not be posted to this Wall. IS any other way to share without passing app id?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should look up what a “URL” is … `p[url]=By Justin Bieber` – this ain’t one, for sure …

Answer (score 1):

i am using following code it was working fine but recently my image is getting load in facebook share box .
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=thisismytitle&p[summary]=thisismysummary&p[url]=http://www.google.com&&p[images][0]=www.mysit/imag.jpg', 'Facebook', 'width=626,height=436,toolbar=0,status=0